# Unable to locate file even when it exist in the internal directory

Tags: android, android-file

This is how i am saving my text file directly into internal storage.

```
String file ="Data.txt";
try {
            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(file, Context.MODE_APPEND | Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            fos.write(query.getBytes());
            fos.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, "File Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            error = e.toString();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: "+error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The file `Data.txt` is created in data/data/com.examples.fileproject/files.
I checked this through DDMS File Explorer.
But when i tried to accessed this file it always shows file doesn't exist.
The code which i have used is

```
file = new File("Data.txt");
    if(file.exists())
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "File Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if(!file.exist())
    {
         Toast.makeText(this, "File Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

I know it is very simple and i tried every possible way. I didn't created any directory even.
But still something is wrong. Hope someone may help me.

Comment: Try file = new File("data/data/com.examples.fileproject/files/Data.txt");

Comment: But i think it is the location for android emulator only. I am not sure about it but if i run this on a device then will this path exist?

Comment: not sure but i think it's the same. try to use *ContextWrapper.getFilesDir()* to get the path, it will return */data/data/your.package/files* so just you need to append your file ("/Data.txt")

Comment: There is no problem with appending the file. Its working fine. The problem is with locating that file by using `File file = new File("Data.txt")`

Answer (score 0):

FileOutputStream fos= openFileOutput(filename,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: Getting the same output.